# Why does the time complexity of the Master theorem differ in comparison to other recurrence relation solving methods?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Consider the recurrence relation `T(N) = 2T(n-1/2) + n`. According to the second case of the master theorem, we would get a time complexity of `Θ(nlog(n))`, while, at the same time, using the substitution method (+induction) we can also get that it is in `O(nlog(n))`, i.e., we can prove that `T(N) <= cnlog(n)` for a c>1 and n>1. Why does this differ, and does it matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Master Theorem does indeed give a bound of Θ(n log n), which means that it says the runtime is both O(n log n) and Ω(n log n). In that sense, it's giving you what you proved using the substitution method, plus a matching lower bound. You could, of course, also prove that matching lower bound using the substitution method and induction, so in that sense the Master Theorem isn't giving you anything that you couldn't previously prove with substitution and induction. In fact, the typical way that you prove the Master Theorem is to essentially find general forms of what substitution/induction would work out to, then doing the math once to prove the general case.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) what a great answer!